# Is there a public API to return data value given file type?

Tags: angularjs, api, download

I am working on a project that involves uploading and downloading files. Currently the only files that can be downloaded are .csv and .txt. The method I am using to download files is below:

```
downloadFile(file).then(
    function (response) {
        var saving = document.createElement('a');
        var filetype = file.fileName.split('.')[1];

        if (filetype == 'csv') {
            saving.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(response.data);
        } 
        else if (filetype == 'txt') {
            saving.href = 'data:plain/text,' + encodeURIComponent(response.data);
        }

        saving.download = file.fileName
        saving.click();
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

I would like to support downloading any file type, but there are A LOT of file types. Obviously I could continue to iterate through them as I have done in the code above but due to the large number of file types this would quickly get out of hand (even if I shoved all the if-else logic into a separate method).

Does an API exist to which I could pass a file type extension (i.e .csv) and receive the appropriate value to provide in `data:<value>` as in `data:attachment/csv` ? If not, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do or am I stuck with the brute force method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a public service to do so, but you might look at "mime magic" server side technology.  It looks not only at the file extension, but also in some cases the content of the file to determine the file type.  For instance, it can determine the difference in a `.avi` file between an mpeg4 and an mpeg2 encoded stream.

Have a look on the [google search for mime magic](https://www.google.com/search?q=mime%20magic) for your platform -- everything from node.js, to php, to apache modules ... and so on.